# Java increment i = i++;

Tags: java, increment, pre-increment

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int i = 0;
      i = i++;
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

This java code is printing value 0.
How internally java assign value 0 to i instead of 1 ?

Comment: use ++i, instead of i++

Comment: `i++`, not `i = i++`.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `i++` is the value of `i` as it was, and it has a side effect of incrementing `i` (which is then immediately overwritten by the assignment)

Try assigning to `j` instead.

Comment: Or not assigning at all.

Comment: "`i+++`" is that the "really *really* increment" operator? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner Typed on iphone where the text box is broader than the visible area of the web page so I didn't notice it.  Not assigning at all does not help understanding the `++` operator.